# Eclipse Mosquitto - Access to MQTT Problem

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Beginner here, trying to install Cedalo-Streamsheets using an Ubuntu VM Image. I am following every step of this page https://docs.cedalo.com/streamsheets/2.5/installation. The last step, is an example to see how the platform works and the following info is given:

> When everything is installed and started correctly the applications
> should be available under the following URLs: Eclipse Mosquitto:
> mqtt://localhost:1883
>
> Eclipse Streamsheets Web UI: http://localhost:8081 Default
> Credentials: User: admin Password: 1234.
>
> Management Center Web UI: http://localhost:8088 Default Credentials:
> User: cedalo Password: mmcisawesome.

The problem is that I can't understand what mqtt://localhost:1883 is and how to get access to it.

Could you help me understand what am I doing wrong?

I tried to paste this url to a browser but it doesn't work. Eclipse Streamsheets Web UI and Management Center Web UI are working fine as I just copy and paste the given url's to a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mqtt://` URLs are for connecting to a MQTT broker using the MQTT protocol.

Your web browser doesn't know how to talk the MQTT protocol, which is why it can't do anything with it.

That URL contains all the information you require to connect a MQTT client to the broker to publish or subscribe to topics.

Unless you want to connect something other than the Streamsheets web tools to the broker you don't need it.